# How To Efficiently Extract Certain Information From A POJO

Tags: javascript, html, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am working a lot with firebase, and am trying to load certain information from the database. The original data comes from a query, and is returned to me in a POJO. The console prints this when the original data is returned:

```
-KhQ76OEK_848CkIFhAq: "-JhQ76OEK_848CkIFhAq"
-OhQ76OEK_848CkIFhAq: "-LhQ76OEK_848CkIFhAq"
```

What I need to do is grab each of the values (-JhQ76OEK_848CkIFhAq and -LhQ76OEK_848CkIFhAq) separately, and query the real-time database again for each one. I can manage that aspect, but I cannot seem to figure out how to separate the values.

I have already tried to get a single output by doing:
`console.log(vals[0])` but it just returned undefined, and splitting the string by `"` would be very inefficient for large data sets. Any ideas?

Comment: What does your POJO look like? `{'-KhQ76OEK_848CkIFhAq": "-JhQ76OEK_848CkIFhAq", "-OhQ76OEK_848CkIFhAq": "-LhQ76OEK_848CkIFhAq"}`

Comment: Can you include the query in your question? Presumably, you've obtained the object by calling `val()` on the query's snapshot result.

Comment: @Shanimal yes, that is correct

Comment: @cartant Yes, that is exactly what I did, and that is what the query returns

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To solve this issue, all I did was convert the `object` returned into an `array` by using this code below:

```
var Array = Object.keys(datalist).map(function(k) { return datalist[k] });
```

Works like a charm, and I can now run a simple `for` loop for `Array`

Answer (score 0):

To access the values, you can iterate the snapshot's children using the snapshot's [`forEach`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.database.DataSnapshot#forEach) method. The keys and values of the children can be obtained using the `key` property and the `val()` method:

```js
firebase.database()
  .ref("some/path")
  .once("value")
  .then((snapshot) => {
    snapshot.forEach((childSnapshot) => {
      console.log(childSnapshot.key);   // The child's key: e.g. "-KhQ76OEK_848CkIFhAq"
      console.log(childSnapshot.val()); // The child's value: e.g. "-JhQ76OEK_848CkIFhAq"
    });
  });
```